# Python list(s) into html table

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to get my display my list(s) into a html table but it's printing the whole list instead of each variable inside it. I'm using jinja2 templates.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <th>Scheduled:</th>
    </tr>
    {% for day in working_days %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{working_days}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Right now it's just displaying the whole list 7 times instead of each variable from the list in a seperate td.

> ['maandag 12 maart', 'dinsdag 13 maart', 'woensdag 14 maart',
>   'donderdag 15 maart', 'vrijdag 16 maart', 'zaterdag 17 maart', 'zondag
>   18 maart']

Comment: replace `working_days` with `day`

Comment: Maybe you should get yourself a rubber duck ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would solve the problem:

```
{% for day in working_days %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{day}}</td>  {# <- not working_days #}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Date:</th>
    <th>Scheduled:</th>
</tr>
{% for day in working_days %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ day }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

replace `{{day}}` with `{{working_days}}`

Hope , It'll Help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need more for

```
{% for day in working_days%}
{% for d in day %}
<tr><td>{{d}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```